# How To Set MySQL unique row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to run this SQL in MySQL database.

```
INSERT INTO
  colors (red, blue)
VALUES
  ('value1', 'value2');
```

but I want that it will insert data only when `value1 !== value2` . is there any way to do that?
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `check` constraint to return an error:

```
ALTER TABLE colors ADD CONSTRAINT (red <> blue);
```

Or, for this particular insert, you can use `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO colors (red, blue)
    SELECT red, blue
    FROM (SELECT 'value1' as red, 'value2' as blue) v
    WHERE red <> blue;
```